# could not insert object, most likely a uniqueness constraint was violated

Tags: nodeos

I started a non producing nodeos using latest snapshot to listen the eosio blockchain but i am getting an error. can any body help me?

Error:

> error 2020-02-24T10:59:50.853 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:388
>   on_incoming_block    ] 13 St9exception: could not insert object, most
>   likely a uniqueness constraint was violated could not insert object,
>   most likely a uniqueness constraint was violated: 
>       `{"what":"could not insert object, most likely a uniqueness constraint was violated"}`
>       nodeos  controller.cpp:1771 apply_block rethrow
>       {}
>       nodeos  controller.cpp:1827 push_block

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused on a smart contract when trying to emplace a table entry that already exists, so if you see this error but otherwise you appear to be reading and syncing blocks, then you can ignore the error entirely as it has nothing to do with you.

You can turn off the output from smart contracts by setting `contracts-console` and `http-verbose-errors` to false.